# Joining 2 child nodes in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file which looks like this with student details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
  <Report ReportType="Student_data">
   <Parameters>
     <StudentInformation>
        <Name>S_FName</Name>
        <Caption> FIRST NAME</Caption>
        <Value>John</Value>
        <Color />
        <Range />
        <Status />
     </StudentInformation>
    <StudentInformation>
       <Name>S_LName</Name>
       <Caption> LAST NAME</Caption>
       <Value>Smith</Value>
       <Color />
       <Range />
       <Status />
    </StudentInformation>
    </Parameters></Report>
```

And I need to join the information and update the xml as StudentName which has both information about the F_Name and L_Name. Something like StudentName = F_Name+L_Name;

Help me out!!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Please show us your current attempt at trying to solve this, and indicate where you're having problems.

Comment: To join you need a common property and you do not have anything common.  Do you always want to take two StudentInformation under the same Parameters tag and join?

Comment: Yes, I dont have anything in common and that's why i am stuck, and I want to take two information and join them under the same parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument to get the required Node and concatenate the result

```
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"PathTOTHEXML.xml");
            var firstName = document.Descendants("StudentInformation").Where(a => a.Element("Name").Value == "S_FName").First();
            var lastName = document.Descendants("StudentInformation").Where(a => a.Element("Name").Value == "S_LName").First();
            var fullName = firstName.Element("Value").Value + lastName.Element("Value").Value;
```

Comment: Plz mark this answer if this helped in solving the issue